# Tomcat 8 java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp

When I try to log in to web application hosted tomcat 8 I get the following error but it works fine the development server with Glasssfish server.

error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.pg.servlet.session.SQLHelper.ValidateUser(SQLHelper.java:71)
com.pg.servlet.session.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:42)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet service(HttpServlet.java:648)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

code:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
    String message = null;

    try {
        validated = SQLHelper.ValidateUser(user, SQLHelper.getEncryptedPassword(pwd));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    if (validated == 1) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Pages/Welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        message = "Either username or password is incorrect.";
        request.setAttribute("message", message);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
}
```

helper code:

```
 public static int ValidateUser(String Username, String Pwd)
            throws SQLException {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        int result = 0;

        String insertStoreProc = "{call ValidateUser(?,?,?)}";

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(insertStoreProc);

            callableStatement.setString(1, Username);
            callableStatement.setString(2, Pwd);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

            callableStatement.executeUpdate();
            result = (int) callableStatement.getInt(3);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        } finally {

            if (callableStatement != null) {
                callableStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: post `SQLHelper` code

Comment: please find the code

Comment: which is line 71 in helper? Check if `dbConnection` is getting initialized properly

Comment: callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(insertStoreProc);

Comment: That means `dbConnection` is null, your method `getDcConnection()` is not creating connection properly.

Comment: private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";

Comment: private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";

Comment: is there any settings do I need to do in mysql?

Comment: `getDBConnection();` debug this method, and see why connection is not getting returned from it. Make sure you have database driver class on classpath